# What are the analogies between decision trees and neural trees?

Tags: neural-network, decision-trees

How can I draw analogies between decision trees and neural trees? For example, how are splitting thresholds analogous between these models, and how can paths in a neural tree be represented in a clause?

Additionally, which structure of neural tree do you advise using, one that is easy to analogize with decision trees?

Comment: decision trees are transparent in their operation whereas deep neural models are opaque, one does not know how a result is reached.